# Why a header file is added in the source code where the function is ALREADY defined?

Tags: c, gcc, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

For example if I have the following three files written in C :

**hello.h**

```
void hello (const char * name);
```

**hello.c**

```
#include "hello.h"
int
main (void)
{
hello ("world");
return 0;
}
```

**hello_fn.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"
void
hello (const char * name)
{
printf ("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

I know that adding  the line `#include "hello.h"` to the **hello.c** tells the compiler that the definition of `hello (const char * name)` will be supplied during an external file (separate compilation) , **but my question now why it is added to the file hello_fn.c at the time hello_fn.c contain it self the definition of `hello (const char * name)` , I mean it will not be supplied from outside ?**

Thanks

Comment: What if the header file contained *other* information, like structures or macros that are needed in both source files? It will also make sure that the function definition matches the declaration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In that case you are speaking it will be needed in hello_fn.c for structures , other functions ...etc , but not for the same function void hello(...).. ? was that correct ... I mean does I had that misconception because I thought the author in the book I am reading from have just added it without any additional need just for that example only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually good practice since the compiler can check your declaration (in the header) against your definition (in `hello_fn.c`).

Without that, there is no way to ensure that they match. You could quite easily put:

```
void hello (int notCorrect) { ... }
```

into your C source file and it would happily compile the two source files independently and then (depending on what you actually do in the `...` bit) fail spectacularly at run-time.

---

For example, consider the files:

```
hello.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "hello.h"
    int main(void) { hello(42); }
hello_fn.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    //#include "hello.h"
    void hello(char *x) { puts(x); }
hello.h:
    int hello(int x);
```

This compiles fine because each C source file is internally consistent in what it states. The `hello.c/hello.h` pair thinks that `hello` takes an `int` while `hello_fn.c` thinks it takes a C string.

I get a core dump<sup>(1)</sup> when running, because the value `42` is not a valid string address. When I uncomment the `include` line in `hello_fn.c`, the compiler complains (rightly) that my declaration and definition disagree (because the `hello_fn.c/hello.h` pair is now inconsistent).

---

On top of that, there may be *other* stuff in the header (though not in your example case) that exists *only* in the header. This is typically declarations that are shared amongst caller and callee, such as types, `extern` items, `#define` items and so on. It makes little sense to declare them *separately* in the header and source file.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Actual* results may vary since this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes , I got it .... you mean it's addition will not add any further information to the compiler , but it will help me ensure reduce possible typo bugs..the compiler will ensure that for me automatically  ? :D ... thanks

Comment: @AbdAllahTalaat: Yes — the headers are the glue that holds the entire program together, and provide the cross-checking to ensure that things work (or, at least, that the bugs are not because of mismatched parameter or return types for functions).  Always include the (only) header that declares the function in (a) the source file where the function is defined, and (b) in every source file that calls the function.  ALWAYS!